# Como usar ckeditor junto com javascript

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Estou Tentando ativar uma função dentro da area de texto do ckeditor como onclick, onload, onkeypress ou onkeyup, funciona perfeitamen`te em textareas "normais" mas quando implemento o ckeditor ele "bloqueia" isso

```
echo"<textarea   id='editor1'  name='descricao' class='form-control' rows='10' required >$descricao</textarea>"; ?>
```

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

$(document).ready(function(){
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function(){};

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `keyup`, por exemplo, desta forma:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
editor.on('pluginsLoaded', function(){
   editor.on('contentDom', function(){
      var editable = editor.editable();                   
      editable.on('keyup', function(){ 
         // fazer algo aqui com keyup
      });
   });
});
```

É sempre bom atribuir a instância do CKEditor à uma variável para usar como referência. No caso, atribuí à variável `editor`.

Comment: Não consegui fazer um alert      echo"<textarea   id='editor1'  name='descricao' class='form-control' rows='10' required >$descricao</textarea>"; ?>
  
 <script>
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' ); 
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
editor.on('pluginsLoaded', function(){
   editor.on('contentDom', function(){
      var editable = editor.editable();                   
      editable.on('keyup', function(){ 
         alert('123');
      });
   });
});
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype._enforceFocus = function(){};

 });
            </script>

Comment: Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Vc colocou `CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );` duas vezes. Apague a primeira e deixe apenas o `var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');`.